# Android Ripple and Timing

Tags: android, material-design, rippledrawable

So i got my ripple working fine. My question is if I set an onClickListener on the button and navigate to a new page , I never see the ripple animation. I can use a handler with a postDelayed for about 300ms, to see the animation and then navigate and that works perfect.  Is this  best practice for implementing the ripple and seeing the animation? This means i need to freeze the page so that I can not press any other buttons during the ripple.

Comment: No, don't block the user from using your app so that you can show an animation. The animation doesn't add any value for the user.

Comment: The value is experience and also a very useful clear hit state.  It also seems to be the go to material design button animation. For consistency one should implement buttons that react the same way. I dont want to block the user , but how else would I do it? Thats the question.

Comment: If the button does something, that's an even more clear indication to the user. It's a good thing if your app responds so quickly that the ripple animation doesn't play.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Android other than Lollipop, the reason is very simple - you don't have the new rendering thread. Ripple animation is done in UI thread which is paused when going to another Activity, inflating Layouts, etc.

Don't block navigation only to show the ripple animation. Such approach would only annoy users.

You can prepare your screens in background and reuse them like list rows. This is how Facebook application works. All pages are ready and waiting for data. This means that you would have to forget about Activities and dynamic Fragment creation. To handle navigation using only simple views you can use Mortar & Flow - library duo by Square. See: https://corner.squareup.com/2014/01/mortar-and-flow.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is good for transistion pages and loading info/ data ...makes sense.  Its not always that you need to load layouts. For instance I want a close button that simply hides a view thats already been loaded. I also want it to have  a consistent feel with the rest of material design buttons which is to have the ripple animation play. Only way to do this is to wait for the animation to play out as far I can tell or just not have the animation play. I have been looking at some other material designs and the buttons are often inconsistent in their use of ripples.